# Send notifications through DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, notifications

Hello I'm building a RESTfull application using Django Rest Framework. 
The clients are android application and react application. 
I need to send a time based notification to users.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using ajax for now and endpoint .

Answer (score 0):

To send push notifications you can use the well supported https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications app

Comment: But it is necessary to pass by FCM for android . Also some problems with the authentication system that drf provide.

Comment: it works for FCM/GCM https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications#firebase-vs-google-cloud-messaging

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use FCM for android. I personally like to use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). If you want to give it a try i suggest to use the pyfcm library https://pypi.org/project/pyfcm/
.
It's pretty straight forward and well documented. As for the authentication problems in the django-rest-framework, please be more specific.